# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

> PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
>   G:\PleskVhosts\peacewithoutlimits.org\httpdocs\admin\includes\connect.php
>   on line 8

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "peace";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

?>
```

Comment: i upload on GO daddy server..

Comment: Are you sure the password for the user "root" is empty? And are you sure you have access to the root user?

Comment: https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/216/connecting-to-mysql-using-php?countrysite=sg

Comment: It look like your db password is not empty. Check your db password once again.

Comment: @Iffi i check again and again..not find solution

Comment: @Blaatpraat in my local server is user "root" and i don't know about Godaddy local server how to know user and passward.

Answer (score 2):

Access denied means that the authentication failed. That means there is an invalid username or password combination. For SQL, it's obvious that the user can be root. So please go to your phpMyAdmin and check from the users tab. You may find out the password set on the root account. And usually online databases are always password protected.

Comment: how to find online passward on GODADDY??

Comment: @zeshan are you serious? Are you really serious with that question? Seems like you're trying to connect to a database where you don't have access to...

Comment: @Blaatpraat yes.. i am serious this question and i am stuck when i make db on server .if i run on wamp they correctly work. but online show error.

Comment: @zeshan When you signed up for the hosting, you should have received an username and password. Or you need to create a schema, and can perform this in your online hosting tool (directadmin, plesk, something else).

Comment: @zeshan go to your cpanel or hsphere (I don't know what Godaddy uses). But I hope at that panel you will see these database and stuffs. Usually, its mysql server, mysql and phpMyAdmin. you choose phpMyAdmin and you will have access to your databases and check for your password.

Comment: @Blaatpraat yes i enter same username and passward but not solved.

Comment: @GideonAppoh yeah i know how to choose but still stuck same error.

Comment: If I should ask how did you create your database

Comment: in GODADDY go to database option and then add database name and database username and passward ..then automatic redirect to localhost @GideonAppoh

Comment: So what password did you provide when creating the database

Comment: peacewithoutlimts1 @GideonAppoh

Comment: if i provide passward then show the error  (using password: yes) @GideonAppoh.. really stuck

Comment: If you are sure you used peacewithoutlimts1, first of all check you password character by character, the case of the characters too.

Comment: Also sometimes web hosts provides a prefix to which you then add your password. Check those ones too.

Comment: you still not give me proper solution @GideonAppoh

Comment: really, then contact godaddy's support for your db password, because it seems you don't seem to have a way around your own hosting package.

Answer (score 0):

the root password could be empty but the option selected is password. At the change password button in your admin, there's a radio button with two option ( 1. No password and 2. Password) Most of the time the password option is selected therefore requires/assumes you have a password. Just get to the options and change to No password option.
Worked for me